# Storing passed data in object twice with `attrs` package

Tags: python, class, python-attrs

I am creating a data provider class that will hold data, perform transformations and make it available to other classes.

If the user creates and instance of this class and passes some data at instantiation, I would like to store it twice: once for all transformations and once as a copy of the original data. Let's assume the data itself has a `copy` method.

I am using the `attrs` package to create classes, but would also be interested in best approaches to this in general (perhaps there is a better way of getting what I am after?)

Here is what I have so far:

```
@attr.s
class DataContainer(object):
    """Interface for managing data. Reads and write data, acts as a provider to other classes.
    """

    data = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))
    data_copy = data.copy()

    def my_func(self, param1='all'):
        """Do something useful"""
        return param1
```

This doesn't work: `AttributeError: '_CountingAttr' object has no attribute 'copy'`

I also cannot call `data_copy = self.data.copy()`, I get the error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

The working equivalent without the `attrs` package would be:

```
class DataContainer(object):
    """Interface for managing data. Reads and write data, acts as a provider to other classes.
    """
    def __init__(self, data):
        "Init method, saving passed data and a backup copy"
        self.data = data
        self.data_copy = data
```

#### EDIT:

As pointed out by @hynek, my simple init method above needs to be corrected to make an actual copy of the data: i.e. `self.data_copy = data.copy()`. Otherwise both `self.data` and `self.data_copy` would point to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things here.

The first one you've found yourself: you use `__attr_post_init__`.

The second one is to have a default:

```
>>> import attr
>>> @attr.s
... class C:
...     x = attr.ib()
...     _x_backup = attr.ib()
...     @_x_backup.default
...     def _copy_x(self):
...         return self.x.copy()
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> i = C(l)
>>> i
C(x=[1, 2, 3], _x_backup=[1, 2, 3])
>>> i.x.append(4)
>>> i
C(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], _x_backup=[1, 2, 3])
```

JFTR, you example of

```
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.data_copy = data
```

is wrong because you’d assign the same object twice which means that modifying `self.data` also modifies `self.data_copy` and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! One question: where/when does `_copy_x(self)` get executed? Is the @_x_backup.default a standard decorator? Can't believe I missed your last point about just pointing to the same object twice.

Comment: The `@_x_backup.default` notation is a way to define a default factory with having `self` passed into it: `attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(lambda self: self.x.copy(), takes_self=True))`. As such, it's executed in the `__init__` that is created by `attrs`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through [the documentation a little more deeply](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=init#other-goodies) (scroll right to the bottom), I found that there is a kind of post-init hook for classes that are created by `attrs`.

You can just include a special `__attrs_post_init__` method that can do the more complicated things one might want to do in an `__init__` method, beyond simple assignment.

Here is my final working code:

```
In [1]: @attr.s
     ...: class DataContainer(object):
     ...:    """Interface for managing data. Reads and write data,
     ...:    acts as a provider to other classes.
     ...:    """
     ...: 
     ...:    data = attr.ib()
     ...: 
     ...:    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
     ...:        """Perform additional init work on instantiation.
     ...:        Make a copy of the raw input data.
     ...:        """
     ...:        self.data_copy = self.data.copy()



In [2]: some_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

In [3]: foo = DataContainer(some_data)

In [4]: foo.data
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [6]: foo.data_copy
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Just to be doubly sure, I checked to see that the two attributes are not referencing the same object. In this case they are not, which is likely thanks to the `copy` method on the NumPy array.

```
In [8]: foo.data[0,0] = 999

In [9]: foo.data
Out[10]: 
array([[999,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6]])

In [11]: foo.data_copy
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```